# Splitting Polyline based on starting point using Shapely

Tags: python, gis, distance, shapely

I have a network of polylines and point data that I am trying to split out into individual line segments based on a given starting point of the network. I know that this can be done using the ArcGIS network analyst extension but I am trying to use open source software. I think this can be done using Shapely Linear Referencing methods but I'm unsure. Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've included a diagram below of what I'm talking about.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. You mention a 'network' which suggests that you have a kind of a graph structure with 'nodes' and 'edges'. On the other hand, you write about splitting a polyline into line segments.
In the drawing the 'Original Network' - is it a polyline (or a linestring?) or multiple lines and multiple nodes?

Comment: The original network is multiple lines and multiple nodes. I want to start at the starting point and split them off into individual segments based on that starting point. Sorry for improper jargon. I should also add that there are multiple other nodes along each polyline so just splitting them by the connecting node is not possible.

Comment: Since there are many nodes, what do you consider the criteria for splitting if not the connecting node?

Comment: The connecting node could be the criteria - I am unsure how exactly to do that. Using shapely I can query out all of the nodes that have a greater than 2 join count meaning that the line splits off into two or more directions. I then have a list of coordinates where the line splits but I don't know where to go from there. Any thoughts?